# Intel Compiler returns "Found Format_element when Expected end of statement"

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

As shown in the following code that I use to practice fixed-form Fortran (because the code I am trying to learn is fixed form Fortran), the 4th format statement and the reading from file 1 are newly added. The code worked as expected prior to adding these statements, but now the intel ifort compiler with no additional flags will not compile the 4th format statement and returns the following error:

```
fortPractice.for(18): error #5082: Syntax error, found FORMAT_ELEMENT 'format' when expecting one of: <END-OF-STATEMENT> ;

        4     format(i6,2x)
--------------^

fortPractice.for(26): error #6052: This label has not been defined as a FORMAT label. 
                          write(2,3)
----------------------------------^
```

The code is:

```
c     This is a script for practicing Fortran codes
      program fortPractice
          implicit none

          integer :: x(0:5),y(2:7)
          integer :: nph(1:6)
          real :: z(4:9)
          integer :: i

          OPEN(unit=1,file='test.txt',status='old')
          read(1,*) nph
          close(unit=1)

          open(unit = 2, file = 'output.txt')

    2     format(i3,2x,i3,2x,2e11.2)
    3     format(1x,78('*'))
    4     format(i6,2x)

          do i = 0,5
              x(i) = i;
              y(i+2) = i+2;
              z(i+4) = x(i)**2 + y(i+2)**2
              z(i+4) = sqrt(z(i+4)) + 10000
              write(2,2) x(i),y(i+2),z(i+4)
              write(2,3)
          enddo
          write(2,*) nph

          close(unit = 2)

      endprogram fortPractice
```

Output is a file created by the program. test.txt contains just a row of numbers: 1 2 3 4 5 6

When I comment or remove the 4th format statement then the code compiles and runs as expected. As I am just learning how fixed form Fortran works, I am just interested in why the 4th format statement won't compile.

Edit:
I have replaced all the tabs with spaces, and the program with some more modification shown below can now compile, but the program does not produce the output file, likely encountered some run-time error:

Edit 2:
Nevermind, I forgot to change the file identifiers.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Are these all messages you get from the program as published? As a side note don't use units 1 and 2 for the reading and writing, they might be in use already, use units > 10.

Comment: Please check whether you have any tabs in your source code.

Comment: If I copy the code you showed and paste it into a .f file, ifort compiles it just fine. There are, by the way, only three formats in the code you posted. The one with the label 4 is the third. The symptom suggests to me a problem with continuation that isn't evidenced by what you posted here.

Comment: There is indeed a tab in the source you have posted here.  That is likely the problem: you cant use tabs.  If that's just an artefact of how you posted here, then there's something else wrong, but you should check.

Comment: I can reproduce the symptoms exactly if I place the "4" label in column 6, or if I precede the 4 with a tab (which makes the 4 behave as if it were in column 6.)

Comment: @albert I will keep the >10 in mind! Thanks. These are all the error messages I get from intel ifort.

Comment: @francescalus There are actually several tabs because i am using notepad++ and when it auto indent it adds tabs in columns 1 - 6. I doubt that is all the problem since the do statements all had the tabs like that. I did remove all the tabs though just in case.

Comment: You CAN use tabs - at least in ifort. It's an extension. If a tab is the first character in the line and the next character is a non-zero digit, that digit becomes the continuation indicator. Other characters following a tab are the statement field. If a tab follows statement label digits, then the statement field follows that. Otherwise a tab is treated as a single blank.

Comment: @JesseFeng it's only an issue for you when a digit follows a tab. See my earlier comment, or the ifort documentation on "tab source form" (which is an extension).

Comment: @SteveLionel I see thanks!. See my update as edit to the question.

Comment: That sounds like useful information to have somewhere, @SteveLionel.  It probably wouldn't be easily found from this question, but perhaps you'd like to formulate a question with that self-answer?

Comment: It's in the Intel Fortran documentation under "tab source form". Are self-answers a thing in StackOverflow?

Comment: @JesseFeng You should start a new topic with the new error, and provide enough detail that we can reproduce the problem. Tacking it on here is not helpful to others.

Comment: @SteveLionel Sure thing! Except I realized I forgot to change the file identifiers in the write statements. Now everything works. Thanks!

Comment: The tab character is not part of the Fortran character set. It can be part of the Processor character set, but use of other characters is restricted for conforming code. "tab source form" and use of # for pre-processor are non-conforming. Most compilers I have used do not report the presence of tab characters, although nearly all the IDE and the associated compiler have different interpretations of the code layout, which is a problem for "fixed source form". Shouldn't there be a warning for the presence of tab characters ? ( and the use of file unit numbers < 10 in OPEN statements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now we have enough information to solve the problem. In the troublesome source line, the label 4 is preceded by a tab. Tabs in Fortran source are not standard, but Intel Fortran (and many other compilers) support something called "tab source form". The way it works in ifort is as follows:

- If the line starts with a tab and then a nonzero digit, the digit is treated as if it were in column 6
- If the line starts with a tab and then some other character, then the character is treated as if it were in column 7
- If the line starts with a numeric statement label and then a tab, the next character is treated as if it were in column 7
- Otherwise, a tab is treated as a blank (this last varies among compilers)

In your case, a tab preceded the 4 so it was taken to be a continuation of the previous line, resulting in an error. Either don't use tabs, or understand how the compiler treats them. Editors that automatically insert tabs will just give you trouble.

Comment: Thanks! Now the initial question is answered. I adopted Albert's suggestion and used different numbers for the file, now the code will run but will not produce the output file.

Comment: DECSYSTEM-10 Fortran-IV used tab-source-form,  See the manual at https://github.com/PDP-10/f40/blob/master/doc/DEC-10-LFLMA-B-D%20FORTRAN%20IV%20(F40)%20Programmer's%20Reference%20Manual.pdf or source at https://github.com/PDP-10/f40.   I used `sed 's/\t\([0-9]\)/     \1/;s/\t/      /'` to make old fortran parse better with newer compilers.